# Parse cloud code is not logging/alerting on success or failure

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am a newbie in Parse.com cloud code. I am trying to query a table which has a particular column having a request parameter which I am supplying. The query is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("newPostNotification", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var userId = request.params.userid;
console.log("User Id "+userId);
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.ViewCount);
query.equalTo('userId', userId);
query.first({
    success: function(object) {
       /*  var userString = request.params.username;
        response.success(userString); */
        alert("Success!");
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
    });


    });
```

I am utterly confused as why I cannot see the the alert messages for success or failure! Please rectify me where I am wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a JSON string. 
For example: console.log({"Log message":"My message!"});

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.log`, `console.error`, or `console.warn`. Check the [guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#logging).

```
query.first({
   success: function(object) {
       console.log("Success!");
       response.success();
   }, 
   error: function(error) {
       console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
       response.error("Error " + error.code + " : " + error.message + " ;
   }
});
```